# R Read & Parse HTML to List

Tags: r, html-parsing

I have been trying to read & parse a bit of HTML to obtain a list of conditions for animals at an animal shelter. I'm sure my inexperience with HTML parsing isn't helping, but I seem to be getting no where fast.

Here's a snippet of the HTML:

```
<select multiple="true" name="asilomarCondition" id="asilomarCondition">

    <option value="101">
        Behavior- Aggression, Confrontational-Toward People (mild)
        -
        TM</option>
....
</select>
```

There's only one tag with `<select...>` and the rest are all `<option value=x>`.

I've been using the XML library. I can remove the newlines and tabs, but haven't had any success removing the tags:

```
conditions.html <- paste(readLines("Data/evalconditions.txt"), collapse="\n")
conditions.text <- gsub('[\t\n]',"",conditions.html)
```

As a final result, I'd like a list of all of the conditions that I can process further for later use as factor names:

```
Behavior- Aggression, Confrontational-Toward People (mild)-TM
Behavior- Aggression, Confrontational-Toward People (moderate/severe)-UU
...
```

I'm not sure if I need to use the XML library (or another library) or if `gsub` patterns would be sufficient (either way, I need to work out how to use it).

Comment: Can you point to the full URL with that select box or expand the snippet a bit?

Comment: I find the rvest package easier to use.  If you can provide a link to the website, someone could code up a solution of you.

Comment: it's HTML. it's a select list in a form @alistaire

Comment: Oops, true. `library(rvest) ; html %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('option') %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide a URL. It is an online DBMS with user access only. I'm a volunteer with the shelter trying to help with some data analysis. I could pull the whole page, but there's likely sensitive data in there. I just took one animal instance to get at the part I need. I can post the entire snippet I pulled if that would be useful. I'll look into the rvest library, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start using the rvest package:

```
library(rvest)
#read the html page
page<-read_html("test.html")
#get the text from the "option" nodes and then trim the whitespace
nodes<-trimws(html_text(html_nodes(page, "option")))

#nodes will need additional clean up to remove the excessive spaces 
#and newline characters
nodes<-gsub("\n", "", nodes)
nodes<-gsub("  ", "", nodes)
```

The vector nodes should be the result which you requested.  This example is based on the limited sample provided above, this the actual page may have unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks, @Dave2e! This worked perfectly! I had a few additional characters to clean up, but that was easy to do with your examples. On to the rest of the data cleaning! :o